# Stop UITextField Secure Text From Clearing Existing Text

Tags: ios, passwords, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that is a password field declared by using

`passwordField.secureTextEntry = YES;`

My issue is that when I type half my password, click on a different component, and come back to the passwordField and start typing again, iOS clears the existing text.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening or turn it off?

-Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, no, you can't do it for secure text fields. You can work around it though.

Implement the delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and use the values passed to decide what to do.

i.e. if the range is the entire string and the replacement is an empty string, don't allow the change. The new text might be provided as the newly typed character, you'll need to check what parameters the method actually receives.

Comment: Just from curiosity, did you tried this solution, because I just had a similar problem (show/hide password) and my problem was when the user switch show/hide buttons and the textField was back again as secureTextEntry the cursor was positioned at the end of the string but if one character was typed the previous string was deleted and just the newly text was "saved" and I ended up by programmatically repostion the cursor at the end of the textField and that did the trick.

Comment: @danypata No, I didn't actually try it so it may need a little tweaking as I can't be sure that the replacement will provide an empty string or the newly typed character. I'll update the answer with this. I haven't actually tried preventing the standard functionality for secure text fields.

Comment: This answer is misleading, the range when the UITextField is being cleared is not the entire string, the range will still be one.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to do this is to implement delegate for UITextField with a code similar to this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)replacementString {
  if (textField.text) {
      textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:replacementString];
  } else {
      textField.text = replacementString;
  }

  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have the same situation when I was changing keyboard type to make my password combo of 4(digits)+1(alpha), to stop clearing `secureTextEntry`,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
[textField reloadInputViews];

return YES;
}
```

It reloads `UITextField` but not its text, so without clearing text it changed the keyboard from alpha to numeric vice versa. You can use it for your own functionality.